# Returning items separately and not in a List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this method that is returning all party members of a certain case and they are all returned to be displayed in one row. I wanted to break this down so that each party will be its own row. I don't all the parties returned to a list and then having that list displayed - i would like to have each party returned and continue looping until all parties for that case are returned each on a separate row.

Current method returning all parties in a list:

```
public IList<Party> GetAssignedPartiesForThisAndAssociatedCases(Guid caseId, int officeId)
    {
        IQueryable<AssociatedCase> associatedCases = _associatedCaseService.GetAll(caseId, officeId);
        IQueryable<Case> cases = (associatedCases != null && associatedCases.Count() > 0)
                                     ? associatedCases.Select(a => a.Case)
                                     : _caseRepository.FindAll().Where(c => c.CaseId == caseId);
        var parties = new List<Party>();
        foreach (Case c in cases)
        {
            foreach (Appointment a in c.Appointments.Where(a => a.OfficeId == officeId))
            {
                foreach (AppointmentParty p in a.AppointmentParties.Where(ap=>ap.DateOff == null || ap.DateOff > DateTime.Today))
                {
                    AppointmentParty p1 = p;
                    if (!parties.Contains(p1.Party)) parties.Add(p1.Party);
                }
            }
        }
        return parties;
    }
```

Currently the method would display answers as:

case #  --      caseName      --     party1, party2, party3, party4, party5

I would like it to show as:

case #  --      caseName      --     party1
case #  --      caseName      --     party2
case #  --      caseName      --     party3
case #  --      caseName      --     party4
case #  --      caseName      --     party5

This is the part in my controller which displays the list of cases with parties:

```
 IEnumerable<AssociatedCase> associatedCases = _caseCompositeService.GetAssociatedCases(viewModel.CaseId,
                                                                                               _currentUser.OfficeId).Where(a=>a.CaseId != viewModel.CaseId);
        viewModel.AssociatedCases = associatedCases;
```

The GetAssociatedCases in the controller above is being called from the CaseCompositeService file:

```
public IEnumerable<AssociatedCase> GetAssociatedCases(Guid caseId, int officeId)
    {
        IQueryable<AssociatedCase> associatedCases = _associatedCaseService.GetAll(caseId, officeId);
        return associatedCases;
    }
```

Which then calls the  GetAll method from the AssociatedCaseService:

```
public IQueryable<AssociatedCase> GetAll(Guid caseId, int officeId)
    {
        AssociatedCase associatedCase =
            _associatedCaseRepository.FindAll().SingleOrDefault(a => a.OfficeId == officeId && a.CaseId == caseId);
        if (associatedCase == null) 
            return new List<AssociatedCase>().AsQueryable();
        return _associatedCaseRepository.FindAll().Where(a => a.AssociatedCaseId == associatedCase.AssociatedCaseId);
    }
```

Comment: are you looking for something like the `yield` keyword or something, to impliment `IIterable?`

Comment: What do you mean return them separately?  can you please post how you want to actually use this function?

Comment: @SamIam I am not really sure of the proper description. But lets say i have a case with 5 parties with the current method i get all 5 parties displayed in one row as a list which is fine. But now i would like to return each one of those 5 parties as a single row having a total of 5 rows. I am not sure how to break it out of the list to return each one without just returning one and stopping.

Comment: @SamIam I went ahead and added an example of what i am looking for. Thanks

Comment: post where you're printing the list

Comment: @SamIam i added more code. In the controller is where i display the information of cases and list of parties.

Comment: Wow, you have a triple nested foreach in which each of the inner foreaches execute a query.  That's O(n*m) queries!  Oh, and to get a distinct set of items you can just use LINQ's `Distinct`, rather than constantly searching a `List`, which is very slow.

Comment: @Amina where do you call `GetAssignedPartiesForThisAndAssociatedCases` from

Comment: @SamIam added more info to original post.